# Docker-Compose, Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, postman

I created a basic web API with the below-shown configuration.

[image]

Then I wrote a docker-compose file for this.

```
services:
  
  dockerapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile : WebApiWithDocker\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3500:3500"
```

When I try to connect with this API through URL
Get:-  http://localhost:3500/WeatherForecast
I got an error:-
**Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established**

How can I resolve this?

VS 2022, Postman v9.14.0, Docker Desktop 4.5.1, Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONTAINER_PORT will be the same as Dockerfile's expose port.

```
services:
  
  dockerapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile : WebApiWithDocker\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3500:80" # HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT
```